# How does the MSE loss function work in pytorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, loss-function, mse

In the following code (extracted from [SentEval](https://github.com/facebookresearch/SentEval/blob/master/senteval/tools/relatedness.py)), a neural network structure is defined which maps 1024 real numbers to 5 output predictions. The problem is to assess the relatedness between two sentences (each represented with 512 features). The relatedness is a number in [1,5]. I think if the training relatedness numbers were in {1,2,3,4,5}, the `cross entropy` was a better loss function, but since in the training set we have real relatedness numbers in [1,5], the `MSE` is used as the loss function.

Question: Since for each input, the network outputs 5 probability numbers, how the `MSE` is calculated between a real number and 5 probability numbers?

```
from torch import nn

inputdim = 1024
nclasses = 5
model = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(inputdim, nclasses),
            nn.Softmax(dim=-1),
        )
loss_fn = nn.MSELoss()
```

Comment: If its a regression problem not a classification problem you should use the mse(mean squared error) as a loss function  to infer real values between 1 and 5 in your case

Comment: @MehdiBahra Yes, but why a softmax layer with 5 neurons is added?

Comment: i don't know exactly , it's not common , but the probabilistic interpretation of mse can help you to understand that http://rohanvarma.me/Loss-Functions/

Comment: @MehdiBahra OK, thanks.